# Generating a stateless, pseudo-random permutation of integers from 0 to n?

Tags: algorithm, math

Question spawned from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338350/java-ascii-random-line-file-access-with-state). The problem can be formulated as follows:

> Given two positive integers n and m, with m <= n, is there a way to find a suite of numbers, which cycles and covers all possible values from 0 to n?

As a basic example, if we take 3 as a number, for whatever number `current` between 0 and 3, we can compute the next value as:

```
next = (current+3) % 4
```

This will cycle. For instance: 1 -> 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 etc. I found this solution by "chance" and it is even general (`(i + n) % (n + 1)` for any `n`), I cannot prove it mathematically. And it is a little too obvious.

Are there better ways to generate such a permutation?

Comment: What exactly do you need m for?

Comment: @proskor let's say, the initial value -- which can be determined randomly

Comment: what do you mean find a "suite of numbers" which cycles and covers from 0 to n?    why not just use the numbers 0...n ?  Do you want it to appear random?   If so I would rewrite the question as "how to generate a permutation of 0..n efficiently"

Comment: Well, for example, incrementing the current value and calculating the remainder of the division will cycle over all values from 0 to n-1.

Comment: so the formula is next = (current + n) % (n+1) ? ... could be (current + 1) % (n+1) which is an obvious cycle (or I don't understand the question / I don't see its point)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others

Comment: @Iftah good point, edited the question

Comment: @Vinze well, it is a little too obvious. I know it will work, though, I just wondered if there existed better ways.

Comment: You could use this sequence, but transform it into a "less obvious" one by doing a modular multiplication by any number that isn't a zero-divisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intend `m` in the question to refer to, or how you're defining "a suite of numbers"). However, one way of getting a cycle of number is to use a recursion (or iteration) of the form:

```
next = f(current)
```

for some function f. For example, linear congruential RNGs use the iteration:

```
x = ( a · x + c ) mod m   where 0 < a, c < m
```

They don't always produce all values from 0 to m-1, but under certain circumstances they do:

```
c and m are relatively prime

a - 1 is divisible by every prime factor of m (not including m)

if m is divisible by 4, a - 1 is divisible by 4.
```

(This is the Hull-Dobell theorem.)

Note that a, c == 1 satisfies the above criteria for any m.  Futhermore, if m is prime, any values of a and c satisify the criteria, and if m is a power of 2, then the criteria are satisfied by any a, c such that a == 1 mod 4 and c == 1 mod 2. However, for certain values of m (eg. 6), the only value of a which will work is 1.

This might not qualify as "stateless", but I don't think that there is any strictly stateless solution; for example, you might look for some function `f` such that:

```
f(0), f(1),... f(m-1)
```

is a permutation of

```
0, 1, ..., m-1
```

so that you could generate the cycle by calling `f(i)` for successive values of `i`. But that's still a state, since you have to remember the last value of `i` you used,

Comment: `m` is supposed to be the starting point, it can be any number between `0` and `n`. As to "suite", well, I guess I could have said "sequence".

Comment: @fge, with linear congruential generation, if you've got a valid (a,c) pair, you can start with any value in the range [0, n), since the cycle is complete. Other than that, I tried to explore what "stateless" might mean in an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Incrementing each subsequent number by *any* number that does not share a common prime divisor with `(n-m+1)` would cover the sequence (e.g. for the sequence `[2-11]` (10 numbers) incrementing by 3, 7, or 9 would work but 2, 4, 5, 6, and 8 would not because they share a common divisor (2 and/or 5)

**EDIT**

I took out the shuffling idea since it seems that you want to increment by the same number each time.  If you want a truly "random" sequence that has m at the first element just take m out and place it at the beginning.  I'm not sure how that helps you, though.

Comment: And so you would replicate this for [0..m-1] as well?

Comment: Well, actually, the thing is, I do not really want to increment by the same number each time, this makes it too "easy", so to speak.

Comment: @fge if it's going to be truly stateless, the operation needs to be the same every time, doesn't it?